# Toilet paper roll falling

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

A toilet roll with mass m and outer radius R and inner radius r is held by its first piece and is released from a certain height such that it unfurls. The equations of motion, taking downward as positive is given by

$mg - T = ma$ (Translational)

$TR = \frac{a}{2R}(R^2 + r^2)$ (Rotational)

If I want upward to be positive and do not want to assign directions from the start and let our substitutions take care of the direction (ie I don't want any negative signs before substitution), the translational equation is given by

$T + mg = ma$

where instead of $g=9.8$, we take $g=-9.8$ with up as positive. My question is how will the rotational equation of motion change.

Thanks!

Comment: you must realize that m becomes a diminishing   function of time as it unfurls? you need an equation using m(t).

Comment: Yea, but the actual question itself says that the outer radius does not experience significant change during the entire process. In which case I assume the mass stays relatively constant as well. So for the purpose of this question, just treat the mass as a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I want upward to be positive and do not want to assign directions from the start and let our substitutions take care of the direction (ie I don't want any negative signs before substitution), the translational equation is given by $T + mg = ma$ where instead of $g=9.8$, we take $g=-9.8$ with up as positive.

If you take up as positive (the $y$ or $\hat j$ direction) then your equation for  translational motion might have been

$T \hat j - Mg \hat j = M a_{\rm y} \hat j \Rightarrow T - Mg = M a_{\rm y}$

without making a choice/guess as to the direction of the acceleration.

Writing what you did

$T + Mg = Ma$ comes from $-T\hat j - Mg \hat j = -Ma_{\rm y} \hat j$.

What is wrong with $T_{\rm y} \hat j - Mg \hat j = Ma_{\rm y} \hat j$ where $T_{\rm y}$ is the component of the tension in the $y$ direction and no judgement is made about the direction of the acceleration?

---

Given the constraints that you have on the arrangement it will look something like this ignoring the hole in the middle with the moment of inertia of the toilet roll about its centre of mass $C$ being $I_{\rm C}$ and the rest of the symbols defined in the diagram and below.

[image]

To compare the two situation all I have done is rotate the unit vector axes about the $\hat k$ vector by $\pi$.

$T$ and $g$ are the magnitudes of the tension and the gravitational field strength and $a_{\rm y}$ and $\alpha_{\rm z}$ are components of the linear acceleration and angular acceleration in the labelled directions.

Noting that a clockwise rotation of the toilet roll will result in the toilet roll moving downwards, $a_{\rm y} = R \,\alpha_{\rm z}$ and $-a_{\rm y} = R \,\alpha_{\rm z}$ are the constraint conditions imposed on the system relating to the two different sets of unit vector axes.

For the left hand set of unit vector axes applying $\vec F=m\,\vec a$ for the translational motion you get

$Mg\hat j - T \hat j = M a_{\rm y} \hat j \Rightarrow Mg - T = M a_{\rm y}$

and for the rotational motion about the centre of mass $C$ applying $ \vec \tau = I_{\rm C}\, \vec \alpha$ you get

$(-R\hat i) \times (-T\hat j) = R\,T\, \hat k = I_{\rm C}\, \alpha_{\rm z} \,\hat k \Rightarrow R\,T = I_{\rm C} \,\alpha_{\rm z}$

Combining these equations with the constraint condition gives

$a_{\rm y} = g\left( 1+ \dfrac {I_{\rm C}}{MR^2}  \right )^{-1}$

If you work through using the right hand set of unit vector axes you should get

$a_{\rm y} = - g\left( 1+ \dfrac {I_{\rm C}}{MR^2}  \right )^{-1}$

The difference being a negative sign.

Comment: I see. That's very helpful. I was trying to not include any negative signs at all though... If I don't want to assume that tension points up and weight points down, or even that they point in opposite directions, is it still possible to solve this? The only assumptions I want to make is that there's a disk, mass M and radius R with a force acting on the centre and a force acting on the surface. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ClovisNyu At some stage you will have to put in some constraints and it is easiest to introduce some early on in the solution.

Comment: I see, okay then. Was hoping to come up with some super equation for all future cases, but I guess its easier said than done! Thanks so much!